# rbind module elements only upon fileInput in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am developing an app where the user inputs several sets of files in a `ui` module, some data tidying takes place in a `server` module to produce a data.frame, and then the results of those data.frames are saved and smashed together in the main `server` to form one data frame with `rbind()` (yes, the data.frames are the same format with the same names).

The trouble is, I can't seem to get Shiny to recognize when no `fileInput()` has occurred and to only `rbind()` the data.frames that are *there*, that is, when files have been uploaded. I tried using an `is.null()` statement but it's not working.

Here is my `ui` module:

```
readCSV_UI <- function(id){
  tagList(
    fileInput(NS(id, "site"),
              "Upload .csv files",
              accept = "csv",
              multiple = T,
              width = "85%")
  )  
}
```

Here is my `server` module

```
readCSV_Server <- function(id){
  
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
  
    files <- reactive(req(input$site))
    csv <- reactive(map(files, read.csv))
    return(list(csv))
  })
}
```

And here is the shiny app:

```
library(shiny)
library(purrr)

ui <- fluidPage(
 readCSV_UI("a"),
 readCSV_UI("b"),
 readCSV_UI("c"),
 tableOutput("check")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

b1 <- readCSV_Server("a")[[1]]
b2 <- readCSV_Server("b")[[1]]
b3 <- readCSV_Server("c")[[1]]

bbind <- reactive(rbind(b1(), !is.null(b2()), !is.null(b3()))) # here is where I tried to recognize it only when files are uploaded

output$check <- renderTable(bbind())

}
```

The above code works without the `!is.null()` statements, but only when file uploads have occurred for each fileInput. How do I `rbind()` only that which has data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `req()` to ensure that the data is loaded prior to display.

Try this

```
readCSV_UI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    fileInput(ns("site"),
              "Upload .csv files",
              accept = "csv",
              multiple = T,
              width = "85%")
  )
}

readCSV_Server <- function(id){

  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){

    mydata <- reactive({
      req(input$site)
      n <- dim(input$site)[1]
     
      lapply(1:n, function(i){
        File <- input$site$datapath[i]
        df <- read.csv(as.character(File), header = TRUE, sep=",")
        if (i==1) all_df <<- df
        else all_df <<- rbind(all_df,df)
      })
     
      return(all_df)
    })

    return(mydata)
  })
}

library(shiny)
library(purrr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  readCSV_UI("a"),
  readCSV_UI("b"),
  readCSV_UI("c"),
  tableOutput("check")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  b1 <- readCSV_Server("a")
  b2 <- readCSV_Server("b")
  b3 <- readCSV_Server("c")

  bbind <- reactive({
    req(b1(),b2(),b3())
    rbind(b1(),b2(), b3())
  }) # here is where I tried to recognize it only when files are uploaded

  output$check <- renderTable(bbind())

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, YBS! Each "site" has a set of 23 files on which some backend script is run. Each `fileInput()` is for one site. How would you alter the above code to include multiple files per `fileInput()`?

Comment: This assumes that all files have same columns.  If not, you need to adjust `rbind()`. Please try the updated code.